# Can't manipulate DropDownList inside an UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net

this is a long one. I'm working on a form which uses ASP.NET multiview. On second view, I'm collecting postcode and doing address look up. The lookup service works fine and returns results. Here is the bare bone ASCX-

```
<asp:MultiView ID="multi_signup" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
   <asp:View ID="mlt_Step1" runat="server">Other data collection</asp:View>
   <asp:View ID="mlt_Step2" runat="server">
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upd_Address" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
        <ContentTemplate>                        
           <asp:TextBox ID="txtPostcodeLookup" 
                        ClientIDMode="Static" 
                        runat="server" >
           </asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="btnPostcodeLookup" runat="server"
                                            Text="Find Address" CausesValidation="false"
                                            CssClass="btn btn-primary findAddress"
                                            OnClick="FindAddress" ClientIDMode="Static" />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="drp_SelectAddress"
                                        runat="server"
                                        AutoPostBack="true"                                            
                                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="PopulateAddress">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <%--Address 1 --%>                            
            <asp:TextBox ID="Address1Txt" 
                         runat="server" 
                         MaxLength="250">
            </asp:TextBox>
          </ContentTemplate>
          <Triggers>
             <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnPostcodeLookup" EventName="Click" />
             <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="drp_SelectAddress" />
          </Triggers>
       </asp:UpdatePanel>
     </asp:View>
    </asp:MultiView>
```

The plan is, use textbox to get postcode, once service returns address, populate the dropdown and set the visibility to true. Once a selection has been made populate the rest of the field from drop down value.

Code behind for `FindAddress`

```
 if (addressResults.Item.Count != 0)
            {
                drp_SelectAddress.Items.Clear();
                drp_SelectAddress.Items.Add(new ListItem("--- Please Select ---", ""));

                foreach (var address in addressResults.Item)
                {
                    //Gets the actual List here


                    ListItem AddressOption = new ListItem();
                    AddressOption.Text = text.ToString();
                    AddressOption.Value = value;
                    drp_SelectAddress.Items.Add(AddressOption);

                }
                //This is not working. On debugger its always false!
                drp_SelectAddress.Visible = true;                 }
```

So technically I cant set the ListItems and visibility of the dropdown... wondering why...

Comment: Anyone around to help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help others so here you go....

I was setting the view index to `0` from code behind on page load. One of my colleague pointed it out.